# Reversing ol numbering

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

How do you reverse `ol` numbering without javascript while supporting ie7+?

I have found solution that are either deprecated and don't work on my current browsers (firefox & chrome) or that use `:before` selectors or children `>` selectors which aren't supported by ie7+.

Ideas?

Comment: `>` is supported by IE7+, not that it'd be related to your question...

Comment: you can try manually reversing `li` display order with css, but that would be just a perversion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting the value of the `li`s. If you have a really long list, you can use JavaScript to set the values. I don't think there is a CSS solution to reversing the order of the list.

```
<ol>
    <li value="3">first</li>
    <li value="2">second</li>
    <li value="1">third</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: HTML5 supports <ol reversed>, but its not supporrted by any browser yet.. 
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/grouping-content.html#attr-ol-reversed

So, just use manual solution or resort to javascript.

Answer (score 2):

you can set `reversed` attribute for the `ol` element to achieve your goal.

```
<ol reversed=true> </ol>
```

I am sure it works on Chrome, Safari and Firefox nowadays. IE.... not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript and jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    var list = $("#list").find("li");

    // count the total number of <li>'s
    var count = $(list).length;

    // loop through each <li> and set value to a decreasing value of count
    list.each(function() {

        $(this).attr("value", count--);

    });

});
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<ol id="list">
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
</ol>
```